# Old springframework works with keycloak

Tags: spring-security, openid-connect, keycloak

I have a web applications:

- app1 with springframework 2.5 It has standard spring-security form login.  I didn't find a solution to enable SSO via Keycloak for this app, because keycloak spring-security adaptor doesn't support springframework 2.5.
- app2 with springframework 5 using keycloak for Single Sign On with authorization_code grant type.

I am integrating these 2 application together by adding menu items in app1 to navigate to app2 pages using JavaScript.  I am looking for a silent authentication option to get tokens from Keycloak after log into app1. Then sent request to app2 with this token.  I really appreciate if anybody can give me some idea. Sample code is even better.

Comment: Do you have any reference of the spring security adapter not being spring 2.5 compliant?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  As of the dependency requirement https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.keycloak/keycloak-spring-security-adapter/1.2.0.Final,  It needs at least spring-security-web 3.2.7.RELEASE

Comment: I would try configuring it as it is, I guess spring 2.5 already supports java config, or you could still try to do it with xml. Otherwise do you have any chance to update your Spring from app1?